# want to copy a file from a server to a client

Tags: java

i want to copy a file from a server to a client in java.this is my code up to now

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class Copy {

private ListDirectory dir = new ListDirectory();

public Copy() {

}

public String getCopyPath(String file) throws Exception {
    String path = dir.getCurrentPath();
    path += "\\" + file;
    return path;

}

public void copyFile(String file) {
    try {
        File inputFile = new File(dir.getCurrentPath());
        URL copyurl;
        InputStream outputFile;
        copyurl = new URL(getCopyPath(file));
        outputFile = copyurl.openStream();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(inputFile);
        int c;
        while ((c = outputFile.read()) != -1)
            out.write(c);
        outputFile.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to Copy File from server");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String a = "put martin";
    String b = a.substring(0, 3);
    String c = a.substring(4);
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
    System.out.println(c);
}

}
```

Problem is , the server is not uploadded online , but it is on my local drive, and the URL thing doesnt work. is there any other way? is this way correct? thanks

Comment: If the file is on the local drive, this isn't really a server/client relationship. Why not just copy the file?

Comment: because on the long run i want to upload the server somewhere. OR i could have the server somewhere on a remote machine (like a unix server) where the code would be compiled and run, and then i would get the file from the remote's directory and copy it on my system( nothing to do with URL's just directories here)

Comment: If it's a server you can just use the loopback interface and handle it just like any other server. And you have to learn to setup the server anyhow if you want to use it anywhere else..

Comment: cz of many reasons , 1 i cant host it , 2 i dnt wana do any more work that in need to.. what else?

Comment: "cz of many reasons , 1 i cant host it , 2 i dnt wana do any more work that in need to.. what else?"  You've written quite enough text-speak & juvenile slang to make me not want to help you, so you can stop there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're expecting to access your file from the local file system (whether that be via network drive or a local disk), you'll need to treat this as if it is a straight file copy.

If you're expecting to access your file as if it is available for download from an HTTP server, you will need to treat it as an HTTP download (which is what it looks like you're trying to do with the URL).

If you want to test the HTTP download functionality using a file on your local system, just set up a simple HTTP server on your dev machine with a directory on your local system, and give your HTTP-downloading code a URL pointing to that local server (on http://localhost, or using your IP address).

Unfortunately, HTTP is a very different animal from a file system, and I don't think there's any way to use the same code to handle both scenarios. If you want your program to ultimately support both protocols, you should build methods/classes to handle both situations, and then have your program detect and use the appropriate protocol for a given path. You'll need to do the same for any other protocol you wish to support (FTP, SFTP, etc).